# Whats keeping these elements from being inside certain divs?

Tags: html, css

Something interesting is happening with my HTML code and I was hoping someone could explain what is going on here.

I have a very simple website with a container div, header div, and body div and it looks like the html elements aren't responding at all to the divs(They aren't going in the div they are between in the html markup).

Was wondering why its behaving this way.

Here is the  html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Andy</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-andy.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div id='container'>

  <div id='header'>
    <h1>Andy </h1>
  </div>
  <div id='image'>
    <img src='main.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html, body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#container
{
  width:1024;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#header
{
  width:1024;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#header h1
{
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#image
{
  width:1024;
  height:100;
  border:1px dotted yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML looks fine, but your CSS is missing the `px` measurement on your widths and heights and your `h1` tag is being made to `float: right;` meaning that the header div probably won't have a height (You will need to 'clear' the header div)

**Edit:**

FYI, a simple way to clear is to just put a div with a class of clear under the content you need to clear, then use the CSS to tell that div to clear, for example:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Andy</h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

There are other ways of doing this, for example: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Hmm okay, I removed the float right attribute from the #header h1 tag to test, and it seems to have cleared up the problem. How would I go about clearing the header div. Putting clear:both inside the header div? or in the next div below it?

Comment: An alternative is `overflow: hidden` on `#header`.

Comment: Ok cool. This worked as well. Not sure why that other guy deleted his overflow: hidden fix,  because that worked too. What is the difference between clear:both and overflow: hidden? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: mu is too short, didn't see you added back your answer in the comments. That method worked as well thank you.

Comment: @Andy: `clear:both` requires extra markup, `overflow:hidden` doesn't, the effect is the same. You should usually go with `overflow:hidden` unless you can't (such as when you need `overflow` for something else), more or less.